# How to return a specific entry?

Tags: entries, sections

Hopefully this is a simple question but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere - I just want to be able to pull in data from a specific entry, where I know the identifier.

In this particular case, the entry is a single. Currently I'm doing this:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').first() %}
```

Is this correct, or is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is the correct way.

**Examples:**

*Singles:*

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('section_handle').one() %}
```

*Channels / Structures:*

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('section_handle').slug('my_slug').one() %}
```

*General:*

```twig
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(5).one() %}
```

See [`craft.entries`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#parameters) for a list of all properties.

Comment: I would use {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').first() %} to get the first entry in a Channel or Sructure, and {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').find() %} to get the Single.

Comment: Thanks Victor, it too seemed to me counter intuitive to have to use `.first()` in a single, however it seems if I remove it then the request returns nothing, as does using `.find()` - have I got something wrong in setup?

Comment: Actually `first()` would still be necessary here. If you want to get an array of multiple entries back, it’s `find()` that’s not necessary, since `find()` is the default behavior.

Comment: So for Single:{% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').first() %}, and for Channel/Structure array: {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').find() %} or {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection') %}, and first item in Channel/Structure array: {% set entry = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').first() %}?

Comment: @BrandonKelly Is there a reason `.first()` is necessary? Since there is only one entry which matches the criteria.

Comment: @VictorIn `craft.entries` doesn’t care whether it’s a Single or a Channel or a Structure. It’s only responsible for taking some parameters, passing them off to the ElementsService, and then either returning an array of all the results (`find()`) or just the first result (`first()`). You can technically use `find()` with a Single section if you want; you’ll just get an array back of that one entry.

Comment: I believe using `.slug()` also requires `.first()` otherwise I can't seem to access any properties. ie `.slug('my_slug').first();`

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question was geared towards getting the entry via twig. Here is how you could accomplish the same from a plugin. In my case, I wanted to find an entry via slug.

**MyPluginController.php**

```
public function actionMyAction() {
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'mySectionHandle';
    $criteria->slug = $this->_getLastSegment(craft()->request->getUrlReferrer());
    ...

    $entries = $criteria->find();

    if ($entries) {
        foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
            error_log($entry->title);
        }
    } else {
        // No entry found that matches criteria.
    }
}

private function _getLastSegment($url)
{
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $trimmed = trim($path, '/');
    $tokens = explode('/', $trimmed);

    return end($tokens);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way would be to use Twig's [`|filter()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) to do the filtering rather than Craft itself.

I can't say how much of a performance difference it makes, but I know that if you're doing very large queries many times, without adequate caching, it could slow your site down if you're constantly making multiple entry queries.

It also allows a bit more flexibility if you're trying to do something non-standard or need a function callback. For example, I wanted to create an array of IDs in Twig and then choose the first entry that matched it, and [`|filter()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) worked well in that situation.

```
{% set featured = [18, 56, 105] %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myChosenSection').all() %}
{% set chosenEntry = entries|filter((entry) => entry.id in featured)|first %}
```